# How to remove angle brackets in my esb while using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, xamarin.android, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

How to change angle brackets into flower brackets in my esb while using mongodb as(DB)

I am getting below response:

```
<ResponseJSON><Body>{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51cad951949c798d7d84de49"} , "empid" : -1.0 , "empdetailid" : -1.0 , "slno" : 1.0 , "nameid" : -1.0 , "inputvalue" : 1.0 , "inputtext" : "NONE" , "finalvalue" : 1.0}</Body><Status>200</Status><Total>5.0</Total></ResponseJSON>
```

I need response like below:

```
{"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51cad951949c798d7d84de49"} , "empid" : -1.0 , "empdetailid" : -1.0 , "slno" : 1.0 , "nameid" : -1.0 , "inputvalue" : 1.0 , "inputtext" : "NONE" , "finalvalue" : 1.0},"Status":"200","Total":"1.0"}}
```

Badly need a solution in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script mediator to write a JS to perform this conversion. Its not a simple < to { conversion, as per your request some part of the request[1] in XML format needs to be converted to something similar to JSON.

[1]`<Status>200</Status> -> "Status":"200"`

Refer to the following link for more information on script mediator

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Sample+350%3A+Introduction+to+the+script+mediator+using+Javascript

Comment: Thanks alot Nadeesha,But i am not a java expert...is there any other way to handle this....

Comment: Most of the code related to your scenario can be found on the internet, You can alternatively use other scripting languages such as Ruby